# Translate routes (url ) for multilanguage website in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, multilingual, codeigniter-routing

I've started using frameworks(CodeIgniter) recently and after lots of research still have many doubts , specially regarding a multilingual website.

I'm trying to "translate" the url , for instance, I have `en/home` and `fr/home` , but I'd like to have for each language its own translation like `fr/accueil` , `pt/inicio`, and so on... 
So far all my system is doing is to change the language but the url(controller) remains in the same language(english):
`en/home` , `fr/home`, `pt/home` instead of `fr/accueil` and `pt/inicio`

What do I have to do to achieve this sort of "translation" or routing? Is it better to create a controller for each language and call them separately? I started doing that but at some point I realized it was extremely massive and probably it isn't a good practice. But I found much easier to create a controller for each language, but then I don't know where and in which file I have to set an "auto run function" to detect/save the language preferences.

Also when I type just the language in my url ( e.g `/en` , `/fr` ) it doesn't "redirect" to the main controller (home):

```
// '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|fr|pt)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

This is not working for me unless I type "`/`" after the language:
`/fr/` works fine!,  `/fr` doesn't work!

Comment: in my oppinion it does not matter if your controller is not the same as the language currently selected, the user will not browse your site using the `url` they will browse it through the `menu` and `links` you provided. That is what you must do. But if you really want that functionality you would have to add or call different controllers for different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully use the approach of setting a cookie for the language instead of having it in the URI, then having all URI segments set in my pages database, for each language, then in my page model I load the correct language URI and text based on the language cookie.

Now the only remaining problem is routing, I set something like this in the end of my routes file, redirecting all remaining requests to the page controller method:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "main/pages";
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = "main/pages";
```

This way I can have both page URI and submeny URIs with my localized version.

Comment: thanks! it is a possibility indeed, as well as to leave the url in english for all languages. but I really I want to achieve this with CI. I know other ways how to obtain the result I want but I think my possible solutions might not be the best ways in terms of good practices and patterns ...