# the correct way to translate website with routes in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, routes, seo, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to provide a selection of language (using a dropdown) for my website that uses codeigniter 3. so far I've been using a `$_GET` parameter to detect the chosen language:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/culinary/detail/123-foo?lang=id">Bahasa Indonesia</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/culinary/detail/123-foo?lang=en">English</a>
```

but recently my manager started using SEO and those two links are considered spam.. and since there are thousands of such links in my website, it made the SEO score very bad. so he suggested to use routes to change the url like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/id/culinary/detail/123-foo">Bahasa Indonesia</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/en/culinary/detail/123-foo">English</a>
```

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21092474/1235167) but I don't understand the answer..

### UPDATE

this is the code I've tried.. sorry I forgot to put it here, I know how you hate people who don't at least try something.

I have this function in my `culinary` module:

```
function detail($param)
{
  // store the 'language' value in a session
  $this->session->set_userdata('language', $_GET['lang'])
  // get data from database based on $param
}
```

and I tried to add this in my `/application/config/routes.php` but it doesn't work.. I mean instead of calling the `culinary` module, it's trying to find a `en` module, which resulting in a 404 error because I don't have a module by the name 'en'

```
$route['en/(\w.+)'] = '$1?lang=en';
$route['id/(\w.+)'] = '$1?lang=id';
```

Comment: why don't you use google translate dropdown?

Comment: @M.Hemant we already made custom translation for the 2 language for about 99% of the website so if we were to switch to google translate now, it would be too much of a waste. also, google translate often give wrong translations.. but my supervisor did say we should use google translate for the rest of the language options..